# I need code to run a SQL Server query which is stored in my local drive via VBA and get data into an Excel sheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have multiple SQL queries saved on my local drive, and each time I have to run SQL and copy data from SQL Server to Excel.

Comment: Can you share the code you tried !, if not take a look at the [this link] (https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/)

Comment: We're not a free service where we write code for you. We help those who help themselves..

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to this.

```vb
txtSQLcmd = "SELECT * FROM xxxx_Log;"
dtDateValue = DateValue(FetchAValueFromTable(txtSQLcmd))
txtSQLcmd = "UPDATE TablevVariables SET [TablevVariables].KeyValue = #" & dtDateValue & "# WHERE [TablevVariables].KeyName='xxxx_Log';"
ExecuteSQLcmd (txtSQLcmd)

Function FetchAValueFromTable(ByVal strSQL As String) As String
Dim cnn1 As ADODB.Connection
Set cnn1 = CurrentProject.Connection
Dim myRecordSet As New ADODB.Recordset
myRecordSet.ActiveConnection = cnn1
myRecordSet.CursorType = adOpenDynamic
myRecordSet.LockType = adLockOptimistic
myRecordSet.Open strSQL
FetchAValueFromTable = myRecordSet.Fields(0).Value
myRecordSet.Close
Set myRecordSet = Nothing
Set cnn1 = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve SQL data from within Excel using default Excel functionality Eg Data/get data from SQL database, you can store the connection and queries it doesn't really require VBA